# Understanding DataGridView.DataMember

Tags: c#, datagridview, datamember

I am having trouble figuring out how this DataMember should work.

It gives me the error `'Child list for field tbl1 cannot be created.'`

I have tried tbl1, table1, text, table1_text etc.

What is the logic behind the DataMember and is it documented anywhere?

How do I selected certain fields to be shown?

```
string sql = "select * from table1 order by text"; // id, text
DataSet ds = new DataSet("tbl1"); // originally just ()
OdbcDataAdapter adapter = new OdbcDataAdapter(sql, connection);
adapter.Fill(ds);
connection.Close();
dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
dataGridView1.DataMember = "tbl1";  // fails here
```

Update:
The answer is

```
dataGridView1.DataMember = "Table";
```

The next question is why?
What is the format and naming here?
Where is "Table" defined?

Comment: Does your dataset `ds` contain one or more tables? If not, the datamember is not necessary. From MSDN: `Gets or sets the name of the list or table in the data source for which the DataGridView is displaying data.` DataMember is useful when binding to a data source that contains multiple lists or tables. You do not need to set this property when binding to a data source that contains a single list or table. For example, you can bind a DataGridView control to a DataSet that contains a single table without setting this property. If the DataSet contains multiple tables, you must set this property.

Comment: @SebastianSiemens thanks, but I still do not understand the format or value to put here. I would prefer a simple example. For that matter we can extend it to select from table1, table2. What would the DataMember be then?